# Commands out of sync

Tags: mysql, nginx

I have nginx as server ( php & mysql). In nginx.conf i place limit_req_zone ( 5r/s ) and from time to time i recive "Commands out of sync error". Some body can tell me why this happenig?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to nginx at all. You have a problem in your php scripts.
See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html